# How to change the default header color in Sitecore's internal applications?

Tags: sitecore-client

We use several environments in Sitecore and sometimes developers get confused about which environment they're currently using. Is it possible to edit the Sitecore applications header somehow, so that each environment has a different color?

[image]

It would be even nicer to put some text in that space, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a module on Sitecore Marketplace which does exactly what you need and even more. It's called **ENVIRONMENT STYLER FOR SITECORE**.

You can find it here:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/E/Environment_Styler_for_Sitecore.aspx

You can read more about it on author's blog: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/environment-styler-for-sitecore/

I'm not 100% sure but I think it's this css line which changes the color of the header:

```
.sc-globalHeader {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #FF0000, #FF8C00, #FF0000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The module that Marek mentioned is great. Another option that does also add text is the Sitecore Extensions Google Chrome extension. It is open source (https://github.com/alan-null/sc_ext) so you can contribute if you want too :)

Here is the link to add the extension to Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitecore-extensions/aoclhcccfdkjddgpaaajldgljhllhgmd

An advantage here is that you don't have to install a module on each Sitecore instance, once its installed it works for all Sitecore sites you visit. A limitation is that you have to use Chrome, that is fine for most people.

Once installed if you are on the web database it will change the titlebar to red and add *WEB* to it:
[image: Sitecore Extensions Web DB]

It is limited to highlighting web vs master - so if you want different colors for each client, go with the module from JammyKam - there are a lot of other really useful features with the extension tho - so maybe a combination of both is the best!